# Updating AKS kubernetes cluster agent pool profile

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I have created an AKS kubernetes cluster with `az` CLI :

```
az aks create \
    --name abcdefAKSCluster \
    --resource-group abcdef \
    --node-count 5 \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --service-principal <...> \
    --client-secret <...> \
    --location westeurope
```

(I followed the steps on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-cluster))

I deployed a bunch of docker, based on unix images. Everything works fine (nestjs and angular apps, but this is not relevant).

Now I have the requirement to deploy a docker image, but based on **windows**. This image is built and uploaded to our azure container registry. I want to run this image in the kubernetes azure cluster. But for that, I need, somehow, to tell kubernetes to run this docker inside a windows-based node.

So I've found in [this blog post](https://anthonychu.ca/post/hybrid-kubernetes-linux-windows-cluster-easy-steps/) that I need to have a `osType:windows` entry in the `agentPoolProfiles` array of json describing the cluster. When the cluster will have a windows agent pool profile, I guess I'll be able to tell kubernetes to target a windows-based machine to run this windows-based docker image. Not sure about how to implement that last bit though...

Anyway my question is how to update an existing AKS cluster on azure to add a windows machine ? It seems this is not doable either with the `az` CLI nor with the azure portal UI.

Thanks.

Comment: With the answer of @Weinong, it not be supported on Azure, maybe you can take a try of ACS with the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-windows-walkthrough).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Windows container is not yet supported on AKS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows containers are now in preview. You have to add a Windows Server node pool like this:

```
az aks nodepool add \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
  --os-type Windows \
  --name npwin \
  --node-count 1 \
  --kubernetes-version 1.14.0
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli).